# How to deal with the lack of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

I have this line of code that organizes the words in *list* into *dictionary* by the first letter:

```
for a in list: dictionary[a[0]].append(a)
```

The problem is, this requires the dictionary keys to each individually have empty list values.  I could do this by adding a few extra lines of code previously, but I want to know if there's a way to have the previous line of code deal with this.

Here's the pseudo-code:

- If the key exists, insert a into `dictionary[a[0]]`.
- If it does not, do it *after* creating the key with an empty list.

Is there a way I can do this in a single line of code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Use `dict.setdefault()` method or `collections.defaultdict()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and not have to change your line of code at all:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dictionary = defaultdict(list)

for a in list: dictionary[a[0]].append(a)
```

Comment: This works quite well!  Is it also high performance, or is it better to just use regular dictionaries over multiple lines of code?  Thank you!

Comment: @Douglas A quick test I ran shows this way to be faster than an equal method of using if / then to check for the keys in the dict first.

Comment: That's very helpful, I'll use this a lot.  Thank you for your help/time!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `collections.defaultdict`

```
>>> import collections
>>> dict_of_lists = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> dict_of_lists['foo'].append('bar')
>>> print(dict_of_lists)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': ['bar']})
>>>
```